# a problem in convergence of bounded of a series

Tags: real-analysis

Let {$a_1, a_2,...$} be a sequence of real numbers with $a_i\ge0$. If $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+a_n} < \infty$, then show that $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x_na_n} < \infty$  for each real
sequence $x_1, x_2,...$ with $x_i\ge 0$ and $\lim \inf _{n \to \infty} x_n > 0.$

---

I am stuck on this problem.Can I get some help?Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps to share what you tried so users can provide better guidance. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Since $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n>0$, we have some $\epsilon>0$ and $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geq N\implies x_n>\epsilon$. We can take $\epsilon\leq 1$. Thus
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+x_na_n} &=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{1+a_nx_n}+\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x_na_n}\\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{1+a_nx_n}+\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{\epsilon+\epsilon a_n}\\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{1+a_nx_n}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{1+a_n}\\
\end{align}$$
and since both of these sums are finite, the result must be finite.